# Get the biggest image from url with php

Tags: php, image, url, dom, fatal-error

So guys, my code for this is:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.google.si";
$html = file_get_html($url);
$largest_file_size=0;
$largest_file_url='';

// Go through all images of that page
foreach($html->find('img') as $element){
    // Helper function to make absolute URLs from relative
    $img_url=$this->InternetCombineUrl($url,$element->src);
    // Try to get image file size info from header:
    $header=array_change_key_case(get_headers($img_url, 1));
    // Only continue if "200 OK" directly or after first redirect:
    if($header[0]=='HTTP/1.1 200 OK' || @$header[1]=='HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
        if(!empty($header['content-length'])){
            // If we were redirected, the second entry is the one.
            // See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#84130
            if(!empty($header['content-length'][1])){
                $header['content-length']=$header['content-length'][1];
            }
            if($header['content-length']>$largest_file_size){
            $largest_file_size=$header['content-length'];
            $largest_file_url=$img_url;
            }
        }else{ 
            // If no content-length-header is sent, we need to download the image to check the size
            $tmp_filename=sha1($img_url);
            $content = file_get_contents($img_url);
            $handle = fopen(TMP.$tmp_filename, "w");
            fwrite($handle, $content);
            fclose($handle);
            $filesize=filesize(TMP.$tmp_filename);
            if($filesize>$largest_file_size){
            $largest_file_size=$filesize;
            $largest_file_url=$img_url;
            unlink(TMP.$tmp_filename);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm having a problem with:
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\agregat\test.php on line 11

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
 $img_url=$this->InternetCombineUrl($url,$element->src);
```

You use $this reference to object that doesn't exists. $this can be used only inside the class and has refference to current object. You can wrap the code with class and you need provide also **InternetCombineUrl** method. The other solution is to remove **$this->** but then you need to create function **InternetCombineUrl** and it will work as well.

Comment: you're welcome you can read more on http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

There error message says it all.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

You can't use it outside of a class. Looks like that code was cut & paste from a class which just won't work without being modified first.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the foreach can go into function, which is wrapped in a class and then I can call this function from outside the class? $this should work then because it will referencing within an object context?

Comment: Copy the InternetCombineUrl() function outside of the class you got, and use it as a stand-alone function, without $this (since you're not inside a class)